# How to automatically share some information in google plus wall

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one, google-search-api, google-signin

I have developed a web application with Google+ Signin. Once user click the sign in with Google+ it authorize the app and register that user. after that process, I want to automatically share some information in google plus wall from my application. For that I go through the Google plus API, "https://developers.google.com/+/" and enables api's related to login, get user information and write access. I'm trying to use Google's API to post on the currently logged in user's stream / wall / whatever. My website uses Facebook and twitter APIs to post notifications automatically on the currently logged in user's wall, but not able to post with Google's wall. I want something like Facebook and Twitter API, with Automatic Posting function and API.
Please help me to troubleshoot this problem.
For your review I am sending my sample code snippet here:

```
/*
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleAPIOnLoad() {
        console.log("Google plus js loaded... calling client.load...");
        gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(e){
            console.log("client loaded...");
            console.log(e);                
        });
    }

    function signIn() {
        console.log("signing in...");
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
            immediate: false,
            response_type: "token",
            scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write"],
            requestvisibleactions: "https://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
        }, function(e) {
            // callback
            console.log("done!", e);

            gapi.client.request({
                path: "plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault",
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    type: "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                    target: {
                        type: "http://schema.org/Thing",
                        name: "Test Name",
                        description: "Test Description",
                        image: "http://test.test.com/Deal/Dealphoto/Thumbnail/0160475582922191382013.png"
                    }
                })
            }).execute(function(e) {
                console.log("did it.", e);
            });
        });
    }
</script>

*/
```

I will be very thankful to you for this.

Thanks,
Lalit

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't automatically post to a users Google+ stream. You can either use the [share API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) with your users intentionally posting, or you can use [app activities](https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/) to automatically create posts that won't be visible on the users stream.

There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41) you can star for a full write API method.

There is a write API in the [Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) but that only works for Google Apps users and can only post private content in that company.